# Convert String to Datetime objects with different formats python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, datetime, strptime

So, I'm working with a data frame with dates stored as string in different formats (why do people do this??) and I need to turn them into  datetime objects. thing is that they not only have different formats but also  are in different languages. I think the only way to approach this is with a `Regex` that matches each specific format and then pass it through as an argument on `pd.to_datetime` function, but I simply couldn't make the regex match any string. I think `Regex` doesn't work with datetime objects such as `%d, %b, %Y, etc`. (I tried with an instance at a time and it didn't recognize them).

If I run `pd.to_datetime` method, it shows an error because of those instances in Spanish or other languages (number 7 and 9). So I thought of creating a regex but I just cant get it to work. How can I approach to solve this?

I'm putting a really simplified example of the DF that includes the different kind of date formats since there are more than 800k instances.

```
    a={'date/time': {0: 'Jan 1, 2020 5:27:21 PM PST',
  1: 'Apr. 26, 2020 12:25:56 p.m. PDT',
  2: 'May 6, 2020 6:25:16 a.m. PDT',
  3: '11/01/2019 18:33:39 PST',
  4: 'May 15, 2020 2:25:12 a.m. PDT',
  5: '30/01/2019 18:35:23 PST',
  6: '10 feb. 2020 21:23:39 GMT-8',
  7: '28 abr. 2020 21:04:03 GMT-7',
  8: 'Jan 2, 2020 2:01:54 AM PST',
  9: '25 ago. 2020 16:07:35 GMT-7'},
 'settlement id': {0: 12493053321,
  1: 12493053321,
  2: 12493053321,
  3: 12493053321,
  4: 12493053321,
  5: 12493053321,
  6: 12493053321,
  7: 12493053321,
  8: 12493053321,
  9: 12493053321}}

import pandas as pd

b=pd.DataFrame(a)
b["fecha2"]=pd.to_datetime(b["date/time"])
```

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: A brute force approach will be like grouping similar dates by its format and parsing them and making to one global format and then combining all the other group results to form single dataframe of dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not too much work, you can make a string replacement dictionary.  For example:

```
MONTH_DICT = {
    'abr': 'apr', 
    'ago': 'aug',
}

date = df["date/time"].replace(MONTH_DICT, regex=True)
date = pd.to_datetime(date, errors="raise")
df["date"] = date
```

output:

```
                         date/time  settlement id                       date
0       Jan 1, 2020 5:27:21 PM PST    12493053321  2020-01-01 17:27:21-08:00
1  Apr. 26, 2020 12:25:56 p.m. PDT    12493053321  2020-04-26 12:25:56-07:00
2     May 6, 2020 6:25:16 a.m. PDT    12493053321  2020-05-06 06:25:16-07:00
3          11/01/2019 18:33:39 PST    12493053321  2019-11-01 18:33:39-07:00
4    May 15, 2020 2:25:12 a.m. PDT    12493053321  2020-05-15 02:25:12-07:00
5          30/01/2019 18:35:23 PST    12493053321  2019-01-30 18:35:23-08:00
6      10 feb. 2020 21:23:39 GMT-8    12493053321  2020-02-10 21:23:39+08:00
7      28 abr. 2020 21:04:03 GMT-7    12493053321  2020-04-28 21:04:03+07:00
8       Jan 2, 2020 2:01:54 AM PST    12493053321  2020-01-02 02:01:54-08:00
9      25 ago. 2020 16:07:35 GMT-7    12493053321  2020-08-25 16:07:35+07:00
```

This will raise an error if it is unable to parse a date (rather than silently fail to convert).  Note that this simple version will replace any appearance of substrings in the `MONTH_DICT` keys that are found.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a generic date parsing library like [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) which supports parsing of dates in over 200 language locales plus numerous formats in a language agnostic fashion.

Renamed the "date/time" column to "datetime" column.

```
import dateparser
b["fecha2"] = b.datetime.apply(lambda x: dateparser.parse(x))
```

Here is the output for your input:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

---

I used parse and all types of formats of dates, return a readable year, month, day, hour, minute.

then I converted those into a string time with specific format    '%Y-%m-%d::%H-%M'

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime
dt1=parse('30/01/2019 18:35:23 PST')
dt1
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 18, 35, 23)
dt2=parse('Jan 1, 2020 5:27:21 PM PST')
dt2
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 17, 27, 21)
dt3=parse('10 feb. 2020 21:23:39 GMT-8')
dt3
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 21, 23, 39, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 28800))
parse('May 15, 2020 2:25:12 a.m. PDT')
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1206: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname PDT identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 2, 25, 12)
dt11 = datetime(2020, 5, 15, 2, 25, 12)

print(dt11.strftime('%Y-%m-%d::%H-%M'))

2020-05-15::02-25

dt22=print(dt2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d::%H-%M'))

2020-01-01::17-27
```

Comment: thanks a lot. although it didn't work for me. When I run this:

parse('28 abr. 2020 21:04:03 GMT-7')

I get ParserError: Unknown string format: 28 abr. 2020 21:04:03 GMT-7

What am I doing wrong?
 what should i be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try the other propose solutions ? They are super neat